# How to correct the figure numbering?

Tags: floats, numbering

Im doing an article but the reference made to the figure isn't matching with the figure number in the caption. (the figure says 1, but in the text referenced says 1.1 not 1).

How can be corrected?
Thanks.

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[12pt,italian]{article}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1.5cm,bmargin=1.5cm,lmargin=1.5cm,rmargin=1.5cm}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{babel}


\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[unicode=true,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksopenlevel=2,
 breaklinks=true,pdfborder={0 0 1},backref=false,colorlinks=true]
 {hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdftitle={Title},
 pdfauthor={Autor},
 pdfsubject={theme},
 pdfkeywords={},
 linkcolor=black, citecolor=black, urlcolor=blue, filecolor=blue, pdfpagelayout=OneColumn, pdfnewwindow=true, pdfstartview=XYZ, plainpages=false}

\makeatletter
\pagenumbering{roman}
\let\myTOC\tableofcontents
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
  \pdfbookmark[1]{\contentsname}{}
  \myTOC
  \cleardoublepage
  \pagenumbering{arabic} }

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\title{\textsf{\large{}Title}}
\author{\textsf{}\thanks{\textsf{\large{}\protect\href{}{}}}}

\maketitle
\textsf{\large{}\tableofcontents{}}{\large\par}

\section{\textsf{\large{}1st section title}}

\subsection{\textsf{subsection}}

texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
texttexttexttexttexttexttexttex \ref{f1}
\begin{center}
\begin{figure}[H]
\includegraphics{pasted1}
\caption{caption}
\end{figure}
\label{f1}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem is that the `\label{f1}` is out of the `figure` environment, so it is labeling the previous `\subsection{}`.

Comment: Thanks, this worked out!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When referring to a figure or table, you should put `\label` *after* the `\caption` command, but inside the `table` or `figure` environment.